# Change color on window resize with css

Tags: css, sass

I use the following formula for fluid fonts:

```
font-size: calc(30px + (60-30)*(100vw - 400px)/(2500-400));
```

I would like to change a color based on how the window gets resized, i.e. something looking like this:

```
 .container {
    color: #FF0000;

    @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        color: #FF00FF;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        color: #00FF00;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
  }
```

Would there be any smarter way of doing it with css only, i.e. recalculating the color value with calc, taking into consideration the vw?

Pseudocode example:

```
color: #FFF + calc(00 + XXX)
```

Comment: Hexadecimal color values cannot appear in `calc` CSS function. [See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: You can use SASS for this, but that's limited at parsing the value ***before*** the page is rendered. If you want changes applied based on events in the page life-cycle, your only option is **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS Variables and HSL colors. And then you could change values in each breakpoint

Something like this:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo4em0fw/)

```css
:root {
  --hue: 0;
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue),  100%, 50%);
}

p {
  color: var(--text-color)
}


@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  :root {
    --hue: 70;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  :root {
    --hue: 90;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hey, i'm some text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's actually what I wanted to avoid - I wanted to get rid of breakpoints.

Comment: @Aiwatko well, then no. It's not possible without breakpoints :)